# Python Flask Restful API

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

Part of my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/api/post', methods=['POST']) 
def post():
    body = request.get_json()
    json_body = json.loads(body)
    new_id = mongo.db.Projects.insert(json_body)
    return str(new_id)
```

Script to post a new database entry:

```
payload =  { 'ProjectName' : 'KdB Test Project' }
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api/post', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

I keep getting json decoder TypeError problems, e.g.

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
2016-08-16 15:19:31,388 - werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2016 15:19:31] "POST /api/post HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have tried several things, incl. posting strings. Any clue what is wrong with the way I post a dictionary?
The problem appears to be at the point of body = request.get_json(). I don't think I am picking up any data...

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to `loads` request message to get dict format. Information stored in `body` variable is already in dict form. Simply doing the following should remove the error:

```
@app.route('/api/post', methods=['POST']) 
def post():
    body = request.get_json()
    # json_body = json.loads(body)
    new_id = mongo.db.Projects.insert( body )
    return str( new_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.get_json

`get_json` is probably returning a dict already, so you don't need to call `json.loads(body)` (this is what most likely causes the `TypeError`).

```
@app.route('/api/post', methods=['POST']) 
def post():
    json_body = request.get_json()
    new_id = mongo.db.Projects.insert(json_body)
    return str(new_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, friends. Unfortuntately, it does not solve my problem. I am getting the following errors:

Comment: Still getting that error:File "c:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem solved. Rebooting the system and/or changing the @app.route to a different path helped.

Comment: @KeesdeBlois: please consider accepting the answer that helped you (the tick under the answer score).